# Application Password not Generating!

Tags: plugins, password, ssl, localhost, third-party-applications

I have installed the AppMySite plugin on Wordpress, but it won't connect fully because I need to provide AppMySite with an application password from Wordpress. I have the most recent and updated version of Wordpress. My site is hosted by WP Engine but they were of 0 assistance, so I'm hoping someone here can help? When I go to type in the "label" for the password and then click "add new application password", nothing generates. I need a way to get a password so I can turn my site into an App that apple will actually hopefully accept. Also, I'm very green to all of this so I'm not good with coding until taught exactly how to get there.